# How to read HCI Bluetooth log on Android?

Tags: android, logging, bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark

I have enabled the `record Bluetooth HCI log` in the `developer options` which produced a `btsoop_hci.log` but I can't view it normally using a text editor on my android (it's all gibberish when I do that) and I can't find a Wireshark equivalent for android too. 
So how can I view the log on my phone itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WireShark` at your PC or [nRF Master Control Panel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp) by Nordic Semiconductor you can monitor your `Bluetooth` traffic.